# data tables scrollx scroll to the last column

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've build a data table with up to 52 columns (weeks of the year) I'm trying to get the page to load and show the current week which will be the last column but I cant get it to display when the page loads?

Any ideas on scrolling to the last column?

Thanks

Richard

Comment: Can you copy/paste what you've tried enven if it is wrong?

Comment: use **https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().scrollTo()**

Comment: datatables.net/reference/api/row().scrollTo()  only scrolls to a row, not column...